# Get the start and end times of the Focused Window from powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I want to get the start time and end time of the Focused Window that is focused through Powershell. The Script used to get the Focused Window is as follows.

```
Add-Type @"
  using System;
  using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
  public class Tricks {
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
}
"@

$a = [tricks]::GetForegroundWindow()

get-process | ? { $_.mainwindowhandle -eq $a }
```

Now I want the start time when the window is focused and when the control is lost(End time). Thanks in Advance.

Comment: As far as I remember, Windows API does not provide such information. Therefore you'll need to write your own application which will monitor the window. Powershell is not very suitable for tasks of such kind.

Comment: Thank you Montonero. I am able to get the start time of the running process but not the Focused Time.